# How long does homemade yogurt take to waste

Tags: storage-lifetime, yogurt

I have been making yogurt this last weeks with a yogurt maker. Just heat milk and add ferment or a previous yogurt (not sure if this is the correct word in English)

Easy and delightful. I store the yogurt in the fridge.

How long it takes to this homemade yogurt to go bad? Also, how long it takes until I shouldn't use a previous yogurt to make new ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most information I see says that homemade yogurt is good for two weeks when kept under refrigeration.

Answer (score 1):

> How long it takes to this homemade yogurt to go bad?

(Where I am, the recommendation for consumers to determine whether milk products are still OK is to check by eye, nose, and taste and if they all agree it's good to eat, go ahead.
I'm aware of the fact that official recommendations in other regions of the world differ. You may be better off checking your local recommendations.)

> Also, how long it takes until i shouldn't use a previous yogurt to make new ones?

I always went  for (bought) new "starter yoghurt" when the result turned bitter (I forget which of the cultures wins, but yoghurt [at least over here] is usually a mixture of two different cultures, and one of them will slowly win over)